# C++11 Variadic Template Function -- where's the error?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

The following code gives compilation errors on both MSVC++ 2012 CTP (with C+11 support) and Intel C++ XE 13.0:

```
template <typename F, typename... Args>
    void apply(F f, std::tuple<Args...>& args) {
       // doesn't do much yet
}

bool f1(char c) {
    return c == 'c';
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    auto t = std::make_tuple('c');
    apply(f1, t);
return 0;
}
```

VS2012 error is:

```
error C2243: 'type cast' : 
conversion from 'std::tuple<char,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil> *'
 to 'std::tuple<std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil> &' exists,
 but is inaccessible
```

Error on Intel C++ XE 13.0 is:

```
error : no instance of function template "apply" matches the argument list
```

What am I missing? Are there really errors here, or do I just have two bad compilers?

UPDATE: Same (or similar) results when I use boost::tuple instead of std::tuple on both compilers.

ADDENDUM: Thanks for all the cross-checks in the comments.  I've sent bug reports to both of these fine corporations.

Comment: Compiles fine in GCC 4.7.0 on MinGW.

Comment: Same on GCC 4.7.2 and Clang 3.2 (meaning it compiles fine)

Comment: Also compiles fine for me, GCC 4.7.1 on Linux.

Comment: [GCC doesn't mind when I nuke the `tuple`](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=e85e6af80c802337a91da6b20ecf8f20). Unfortunately that website gives no indication as to compiler version. I'm told it's GCC 4.7.2, though. Also I can't see any obvious reason for your code to fail.

Comment: It is the latest release of GCC.  But I might suspect that the body of `apply` is the cause, as it is unspecified.

Comment: @DeadMG: The error occurs with the code as is, no body necessary.

Comment: @DavidH : The VC++ 2012 Community Technology Preview is, well, a _preview_. Think alpha-quality, and _expect_ bugs. No comment regarding ICC. :-]

Comment: If someone has the time, rip out the guts of Visual Studio's tuple implementation, making syntax changes if necessary, and compile it with GCC or Clang.  I would expect a similar result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is likely a VC11 bug in the implementation of the Standard Library. Although the CTP supports variadic templates, to the best of my knowledge the Standard Library was not rewritten to use them and adopts some machinery to simulate variadic templates. This is likely at the origin of your problem.

Comment: No, it should still match.

Comment: @AndyProwl -- std::tuples didn't exist before C++11, I believe (we had to use tr1 or boost)

Comment: @DavidH: The open-source implementation of `boost::tuple` didn't have variadic templates either and perhaps CTP was "inspired" by that

Comment: @DavidH: But Visual Studio has supported `std::tuple` since version 10, to the best of its ability without variadic templates.

Comment: @DavidH: if I'm not mistaken, VS2012 before the CTP had an implementation of the C++11 Standard Library which did include `std::tuple`. This implementation was not based on variadic templates, and was not rewritten after the CTP was released with support for variadic templates. I did not mean to say that `std::tuple` existed before C++11.

Comment: @DeadMG: not that I don't believe you, but could you please explain why?

Comment: @Andy : Fully agreed with your last comment.